# Selecting a specific subclass using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply styling to a specific element using CSS.

The HTML for the element looks like the following:

```
<div class="wrapper red-background ">
content here
</div>
```

Im trying to select and style this element using the following CSS:

```
.wrapper .red-background {
float:right !important;
width:230px !important;
padding-right:20px !important;
padding-top:0px !important;
};
```

However it does not seem to pick it up at all, I cant figure out what i am doing wrong. The styling is not being overwritten, its just not being applied in the first place. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a definition that is to match two or more classes on one element, do not include a space.

`.wrapper.red-background`

What you've provided would look for a `.red-background` inside a `.wrapper`

Comment: A very simple question, but this is one of the very few answers that is actually correct *and* also describes why it is correct compared to the code in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Your selector is incorrect.

A space between class names in a selector indicates that you are trying to select a descendant of the original class.

So `.a .b` indicates you are trying to select the div with a class of `b` inside a div `with a class of`a`.

```
<div class="a">
   <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

For elements with multiple classes, one merely chain the classes. So for this..

```
<div class="a b">
</div>
```

You need `.a.b`

Therefore...

**For this HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper red-background ">
content here
</div>
```

The selector would be without a space.

```
.wrapper.red-background {
float:right !important;
width:230px !important;
padding-right:20px !important;
padding-top:0px !important;
}
```

Comment: A simple question with a simple answer, but this answer could use some description why this is correct, while in other situations you would need the space.

Answer (score 1):

don't give space in css class

```
.wrapper.red-background {
float:right !important;
width:230px !important;
padding-right:20px !important;
padding-top:0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help you to understand CSS selectors: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```
.wrapper.red-background {
   float:right !important;
   width:230px !important;
   padding-right:20px !important;
   padding-top:0px !important;
};
```

If you seperate the two classes, the last one is a child element. You need to combine them like above: without spaces. So only elements with BOTH classes will be styled.

Answer (score 0):

Lose the space between classes in the CSS:

```
.wrapper.red-background {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
.wrapper {
    float: right;
    width: 230px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

- You'll want to remove the ; from after the closing }

Also

- You don't need the !importants unless you're trying to override something written in the css below. (edit, I had originally written 'above')
- Does the target div need to contain **both** wrapper and red-background classes? Or just one of the two? The above css assumes just one of the two while others have answered assuming the obvious, that both are a requirement.

Comment: the end ";" seems to be one of the root causes for what was causing this issue once i resolved the rest, I think i was unintentionally closing the entire stylesheet by mistake. Excellent spot! would have taken me ages to notice that by myself!

Comment: Thank you for the reply, with all the down votes I was starting to wonder where I went wrong.

Comment: Your answer works, but it is wrong. It selects all elements that have a `red-background` in their class list. What the OP wants, is to select elements that have **both** `wrapper` and `red-background` in their class list. Others replied correctly.

Comment: Though it's stated a specific element need be styled it's not stated that specific element need contain both wrapper and red-background classes. It would be an easy assumption but I went with another assumption, based on the general question and css error. I see now one grave error that needs correcting, that of important overriding css 'above'.

Comment: maybe you didnt answer the answer fully correctly (i still need that level of specificity) but you pointed out a really annoying and simple error that would have taken me ages to find otherwise. So im happy!